# Use .json file or database for static data?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, database, firebase

I am building a web app using nodeJS with an angular based frontend and a Firebase/AngularFire2 backend.  I have a list of about 80 cities and couple of details about each of them that I need to display with checkboxes for the user.

Should I save them as a json object in a .json file on the server and call it, or just store it in my Real-time Database and query it?  Are there any speed/memory benefits to either?

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios :

1.Your task is search oriented. You have to query the data and manipulate it. Memory management is key issues for you. You want some complex searching methods on your data. **Then go for the database.**

2.Your task require whole data at a time. You don't need to worry about memory management. **Then directly load the data from file.** Obviously this method will save the connection making time with your database. It will work as simple as file streams. **[suggested for your case]**